# what's wrong with this code at sessionloginid

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my first code I wrote in php I follow tutorials.. I want this code to select all fields in privilege table  and check the id of user who logged in and his access level 
but the   access level doesn't change with every user logged in

I use relation between  two tables they are:
privilege table

```
+----------------------------------+
|  AccessLevel | logi_id  | pre_id |
|----------------------------------|
|      1       |    1     |   1    |
|      2       |    1     |   2    | 
|      4       |    2     |   4    |
+----------------------------------+
```

and this is login_pre table:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  username| userpass | login_id   |
|----------------------------------|
|      a   |    123   |   1        |
|      a   |    123   |   1        | 
|      b   |   1234   |   2        |
+----------------------------------+
```

this is access page :

```
     <?php
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\connection\connect.php';
        $query ="SELECT * FROM privilege " ;
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
            $access = $row['AccessLevel'];

                echo $access; //result 124 in database

                        }

            if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
            {           
            echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess']=$access;// "that is print  wrong result " access level doesn't change based on user logged in 

            echo $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];

                    }

            ob_end_flush();
        ?>
```

and this is login page:

```
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
        $loginid = $_POST['login_id'];


if($username && $userpass )
{
    $finduser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM login_pre WHERE username = '".$username."' AND userpass = '".$userpass."'") or die("error");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($finduser) !=0)
        {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($finduser))
                {$uname = $row['username'];
                $upass = $row['userpass'];
                $uloginid = $row['login_id'];
                }

        }

        if($username == $uname && $userpass == $upass  )
            {
                $_SESSION['sessionname'] =$uname;
            $_SESSION['sessionpass'] =$upass;
            $_SESSION['sessionloginid'] =$uloginid;

        echo $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];//result 124 of users

            }else header("location: login2.php");
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: So you want to retrieve the access level of those users who are logged in??..For eg: user with login id `1` should display access level `12`..is it so??

Comment: why not just do a join to get resultant priv when you lookup the username and pw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query need to be modified. Add a condition to retrieve `access level` of those that are matching the current `$_SESSION['sessionloginid']`. Try this:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
        {  
        $query ="SELECT * FROM privilege where logi_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
        $access = $row['AccessLevel'];

            echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess']=$access;
            echo $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];
                    }
                }

        ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```